# How to monitor more than one log file at a time

Tags: java, monitoring, logging

Is there any Java API to monitor more than one log file at a time. i.e.in  `TailerListener` we are able to monitor a single log file.

Please let me know if any Java API or any simple methods to monitor more than one log file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand the question. what exactly are you trying to do?

and did you try using log4j? if i understand the question you can make as many different log files as you like.

Comment: From java,i want to monitor the more log files at same time and return the log message when log messages are match with string pattern

Comment: He want's to *read* log files and monitor them for changes, not create them!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/). It uses the Linux [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) subsystem.

From the web page:

```
JNotify is a java library that allow java application to listen to file system events, such as:
 - File created 
 - File modified 
 - File renamed 
 - File deleted
```

There are a couple of other inotify implementations for java out there, and this is a good [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) on the topic.

- [inotify-java](https://launchpad.net/inotify-java)
- [JFileNotify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfilenotify/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply [create multiple `Tailer` objects](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html#create%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListener%29) using the same [`TailerListener`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListener.html) instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.if log files are more,we need to create more objects.that's what i am asking is there any other way to do this.please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: So what's wrong with creating more objects? You want them to do more work after all. Keep in mind that duing something like `tail` without native support by the OS/VM will be kind-of expensive anyway (since you will need to do polling either manually or encapsulated within the library you use).

Comment: in java,is there any API like multitail in linux.